# Dynamic DNS Entry using bind & dnsjava

Tags: java, dns, bind

I need to insert a host url into a Bind DNS zone using javadns. I generated a TSIG key and configured bind config files.

I'm not sure about the DNS zone allow-update issue. Should I enter valid IPs or TSIG keys?

Here is the code I implemented with javadns:

```
Name zone = Name.fromString("ns1.dns.com.");
Name host = Name.fromString("some.host.com", zone);

Resolver res = new SimpleResolver(dnsIp);
res.setTSIGKey(new TSIG("my_tsig_key", key));
res.setTCP(true);

Update update = new Update(zone);
update.add(host, Type.A, 86400, "1.2.3.4");
Message response = res.send(update);
System.out.println(response);
```

**CONSOLE:**

> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: UPDATE, status: NOTAUTH, id: 22225 ;; flags:
>   qr ra ; qd: 1 an: 0 au: 0 ad: 1  ;; TSIG ok ;; ZONE: ;;   ns1.dns.com.,
>   type = SOA, class = IN
>
> ;; PREREQUISITES:
>
> ;; UPDATE RECORDS:
>
> ;; ADDITIONAL RECORDS:
>   ns1.domain.com.       0   ANY TSIG    hmac-md5.sig-alg.reg.int. 1465835914 300
>   16 xXqHHVOp5tOnebnSGynXMQ== NOERROR 0
>
> ;; Message size: 116 bytes

**SYSLOG:**

> Jun 13 19:38:34 atar-srv named[2632]: client 192.168.200.23#57543/key
>   ns1.dns.com: updating zone 'dns.com/IN': update failed: not
>   authoritative for update zone (NOTAUTH)

Answer (score 1):

It is important to consider your key algorithm. The constructor

> public TSIG(String KeyName , String keySecret)

is working with hmac-md5 algorithm according to [javadoc for dnsjava](https://javadoc.io/doc/dnsjava/dnsjava/2.1.9) (Look at the class TSIG and its constructors).
If you want to use other algorithm you should provide your algorithm to this constructor :

```
public TSIG(java.lang.String algorithm,
            java.lang.String name,
            java.lang.String key)
```

and these are legal algorithm value:
"HmacMD5",
"HmacSHA1",
"HmacSHA224",
"HmacSHA256",
"HmacSHA384",
"HmacSHA512"